# Compare two lists to get waterfall chart data in LinQ

Tags: c#, linq

My object has 3 fields - Term, Subject and Marks. I want to have a list of items whose marks are different for any subject.

eg:

First list

```
 Term1, English,90
 Term1, Maths, 60
 Term1, Physics, 30
```

Second list

```
 Term2, English, 95
 Term2,Maths, 60
 Term2, Chemistry, 20
```

Finally what i want is

```
English : +5
Physics : +30
Chemistry : -20.
```

I am using the below query to get difference, but it fails if the key field(subject in this case) values are not same in the two list(eg:-Chemistry present in List2 but not in List1)

```
   var diffData = list1.Union(list2)
                        .GroupBy(m => m.Subject)
                        .Select(d=>
                        {
                            Subject= d.Key,
                            Difference = d.OrderBy(m =>m.Term).Select(s => s.Mark).Aggregate(t1, t2) => t2 - t1)
                        }).Where(m => m.Difference != 0).ToList();
```

Please help

Comment: Do you want Chemistry to be +20 and Physics to be -30?  It seems like that would be more consistent with English being +5.

Comment: @steaks I need a full outer join. I common categoires are ther then I need their difference

Comment: I understand that you want a full outer join.  However, i don't understand how you want to take the difference.  There's no consistent way to take the difference given the signs of the differences for English, Physics, and Chemistry.

Comment: I'dont understand how Chemistry has 20 points but the result shows -20?. The difference between 0 in Term1 (because it wasn't there yet) and 20 in Term2 is still 20.

Comment: @Serv its just a genaralization of my problem. Consider that I need to know that value comes from second list

Answer (score 1):

```
var diffs = list1.Union(list2)
    //Create groups where the key is subject and the value is the 
    //list of positive marks for Term2 and negative marks for Term1
    .GroupBy(c => c.Subject, c => c.Term == "Term2" ? c.Mark : -c.Mark)
    .Select(s => new
        {
            Subject = s.Key,
            Difference = s.Sum()
        })
    .Where(s => s.Difference != 0);

var diffs2 = list1.Union(list2)
    .GroupBy(c => c.Subject)
    .Select(s =>
        {
            //For a more general and slighly different algorithm, you can 
            //subtract all the marks for a each subject except the last term 
            //mark from the last term mark (e.g. 95 - 90 for English or 30 - 
            //n/a because there's only one term for Physics
            var marks = s.OrderByDescending(c => c.Term).Select(c => c.Mark);
            var lastTermMark = marks.First();
            return new
                {
                    Subject = s.Key,
                    Difference = marks.Skip(1)
                        .Aggregate(lastTermMark, (diff, mark) => diff - mark)
                };
        })
    .Where(s => s.Difference != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way you simply got your Output

```
var Outpt = (from a in List1
             from b in List2
             where a.Subject == b.Subject
             Select new {subject = a.subject , marks = a.marks - b.marks , a.Term}).ToList();
```

Comment: @ Co.Aden  Nope. Please understand the question. If I apply the above query I will miss physics,chemistry  as they are not common in lists